# ffmpeg for android build - is it complete

Tags: android, linux, build, ffmpeg

//EDIT save time and refer to the [SF project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/) . IMO, it may save a ton of work getting up to speed.....

after more work on this issue:

added a git [project](https://github.com/rowntreerob/android-ffmpeg)

build is easier with custom toolchain installed so that you can invoke [compiler the easy way](http://source-android.frandroid.com/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html)

sample stdout from [ndk-build](http://pastebin.com/y04cmXBM)

--
originally used ubuntu 12.04 inside vmplayer on windows vista. IMO linux is better for builds than cygwin.

I follow these [instructions](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/comment-page-5) getting a indeterminant outcome in which the following conditions exist.

> build_android.sh seems to exit normally
>   config.log has error where confirming gcc from crosstoolchain
>   all the static libs are built ok
>      (./libavfilter, ./libavcodec etc )
>   ffmpeg.o is there and executes ok
>   no  ./android directory as per the prefix setting to config

it looks like i can just push the binaries to my phone and test in a shell. If that's ok then i can look to a jni wrapper for the static libs.

But why didn't the build write anything to --prefix=./android/armv7-a  ??
that path does not exist at the conclusion of the build

Details:

config log what was processed:

```
FFMPEG_CONFIGURATION='--target-os=linux --prefix=./android/armv7-a 
--enable-libvpx --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --logfile=config.log
--enable-cross-compile --extra-libs=-lgcc --arch=arm 
--cc=/home/rob/src/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc 
--cross-prefix=/home/rob/src/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- 
--nm=/home/rob/src/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm 
--sysroot=/home/rob/src/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/ --extra-cflags='"'"' -O3 -fpic 
-DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums 
-fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 -mfloat-abi=softfp  -marm -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 '"'"' 
--disable-shared --enable-static --extra-ldflags='"'"'
-Wl,-rpath-link=/home/rob/src/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-14/arch-arm//usr/lib -L/home/rob/src/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-14/arch-arm//usr/lib 
-nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog'"'"' 
--disable-everything --enable-demuxer=mov --enable-demuxer=h264 
--disable-ffplay --enable-protocol=file 
--enable-avformat --enable-avcodec --enable-decoder=rawvideo 
--enable-decoder=mjpeg --enable-decoder=h263 --enable-decoder=mpeg4 
--enable-decoder=h264 --enable-parser=h264 --disable-network --enable-zlib --disable-avfilter --disable-avdevice'
```

tail of config log contains error on compiler check

```
zmbv_test='yes'
zmbv_test_deps='zlib'
WARNING: /home/rob/src/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.
mktemp -u XXXXXX
Yd2A0h
WARNING: Unknown C compiler /home/rob/src/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc, unable to select optimal CFLAGS
check_ld cc
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.m9Kg3cqt.c
    1   int main(void){ return 0; }
END /tmp/ffconf.m9Kg3cqt.c
/home/rob/src/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 -mfloat-abi=softfp -marm -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -c -o /tmp/ffconf.tO2EIBz5.o /tmp/ffconf.m9Kg3cqt.c
./configure: 640: ./configure: /home/rob/src/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: not found
C compiler test failed.
```

tail of build_android.sh stdout looks OK

```
libavutil/opt.c: In function ‘av_find_opt’:
libavutil/opt.c:41:5: warning: ‘av_next_option’ is deprecated (declared at libavutil/opt.h:347) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
CC  libavutil/pixdesc.o
libavutil/opt.c: In function ‘av_opt_set_defaults’:
libavutil/opt.c:601:5: warning: ‘av_opt_set_defaults2’ is deprecated (declared at libavutil/opt.h:370) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
CC  libavutil/random_seed.o
CC  libavutil/rational.o
CC  libavutil/rc4.o
CC  libavutil/samplefmt.o
CC  libavutil/sha.o
CC  libavutil/timecode.o
CC  libavutil/tree.o
CC  libavutil/utils.o
CC  libavutil/x86/cpu.o
INSTALL libavdevice/avdevice.h
INSTALL presets/libvpx-1080p50_60.ffpreset
INSTALL presets/libvpx-1080p.ffpreset
INSTALL presets/libvpx-360p.ffpreset
INSTALL presets/libvpx-720p50_60.ffpreset
INSTALL presets/libvpx-720p.ffpreset
INSTALL presets/libx264-ipod320.ffpreset
INSTALL presets/libx264-ipod640.ffpreset
INSTALL doc/ffprobe.xsd
INSTALL libavdevice/libavdevice.pc
INSTALL libavfilter/asrc_abuffer.h
INSTALL libavfilter/avcodec.h
INSTALL libavfilter/avfilter.h
INSTALL libavfilter/avfiltergraph.h
INSTALL libavfilter/buffersink.h
INSTALL libavfilter/version.h
INSTALL libavfilter/vsrc_buffer.h
INSTALL libavfilter/libavfilter.pc
INSTALL libavformat/avformat.h
INSTALL libavformat/avio.h
INSTALL libavformat/version.h
INSTALL libavformat/libavformat.pc
INSTALL libavresample/avresample.h
INSTALL libavresample/version.h
INSTALL libavresample/libavresample.pc
INSTALL libavcodec/avcodec.h
INSTALL libavcodec/avfft.h
INSTALL libavcodec/dxva2.h
INSTALL libavcodec/vaapi.h
INSTALL libavcodec/vda.h
INSTALL libavcodec/vdpau.h
INSTALL libavcodec/version.h
INSTALL libavcodec/xvmc.h
INSTALL libavcodec/libavcodec.pc
INSTALL libswresample/libswresample.pc
INSTALL libswresample/swresample.h
INSTALL libswscale/swscale.h
INSTALL libswscale/libswscale.pc
INSTALL libavutil/adler32.h
INSTALL libavutil/aes.h
INSTALL libavutil/attributes.h
INSTALL libavutil/audio_fifo.h
INSTALL libavutil/audioconvert.h
INSTALL libavutil/avassert.h
INSTALL libavutil/avstring.h
INSTALL libavutil/avutil.h
INSTALL libavutil/base64.h
INSTALL libavutil/bprint.h
INSTALL libavutil/bswap.h
INSTALL libavutil/common.h
INSTALL libavutil/cpu.h
INSTALL libavutil/crc.h
INSTALL libavutil/error.h
INSTALL libavutil/eval.h
INSTALL libavutil/fifo.h
INSTALL libavutil/file.h
INSTALL libavutil/imgutils.h
INSTALL libavutil/intfloat.h
INSTALL libavutil/intfloat_readwrite.h
INSTALL libavutil/intreadwrite.h
INSTALL libavutil/lfg.h
INSTALL libavutil/log.h
INSTALL libavutil/lzo.h
INSTALL libavutil/mathematics.h
INSTALL libavutil/md5.h
INSTALL libavutil/mem.h
INSTALL libavutil/dict.h
INSTALL libavutil/opt.h
INSTALL libavutil/parseutils.h
INSTALL libavutil/pixdesc.h
INSTALL libavutil/pixfmt.h
INSTALL libavutil/random_seed.h
INSTALL libavutil/rational.h
INSTALL libavutil/samplefmt.h
INSTALL libavutil/sha.h
INSTALL libavutil/timecode.h
INSTALL libavutil/timestamp.h
INSTALL libavutil/avconfig.h
INSTALL libavutil/libavutil.pc
AR  libavdevice/libavdevice.a
AR  libavfilter/libavfilter.a
AR  libavformat/libavformat.a
AR  libavresample/libavresample.a
AR  libavcodec/libavcodec.a
AR  libswresample/libswresample.a
AR  libswscale/libswscale.a
AR  libavutil/libavutil.a
INSTALL libavdevice/libavdevice.a
INSTALL libavfilter/libavfilter.a
INSTALL libavresample/libavresample.a
INSTALL libswresample/libswresample.a
INSTALL libswscale/libswscale.a
INSTALL libavutil/libavutil.a
INSTALL libavformat/libavformat.a
LD  ffmpeg_g
INSTALL libavcodec/libavcodec.a
CP  ffmpeg
STRIP   ffmpeg
INSTALL install-progs-yes
INSTALL ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "not found" error isn't indicating that arm-linux-androideabi-gcc isn't found, that error is being returned *from* arm-linux-androideabi-gcc, most likely because of an erroneous flag. Since your --cross-prefix is set correctly you can remove the --cc and --nm lines. If you alter the cross-prefix slightly (take the - off the end for instance) you'll see that the not found error will change to a less ambiguous one.

Try getting rid of everything but "-DANDROID -mfloat-abi=softfp -marm -march=armv7-a" in your extra cflags, and remove the crazy extra quotation marks and see if it compiles.

Comment: hey it worked for me. but meanwhile i got some warnings dat some functions are deprecated and "libavcodec/aacps.c:352:9: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘hybrid4_8_12_cx’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
libavcodec/aacps.c:331:13: note: expected ‘const float (*)[8][2]’ but argument is of type ‘float (*)[8][2]’
"  . shall i ignore it?

Comment: Damn, I had to remove everything from the extra-cflags except for "-DANDROID" and my issue with .mak files got solved. Thanks.

Comment: please give me build_android.sh file

Answer (score 0):

This is what the guide you followed says:

> Once the script finishes execution, there’ll be a folder called
>   android under ffmpeg-0.8 directory, which contains all the output of
>   the build.

Comment: thanks .. that folder is empty. stdout from build_android.sh looks normal though. no errors.

Comment: Note the error above on the compiler check in the tail of 'config.log' stating that the c-compiler does not exist.. well its there, but i may a permissions issue or may need to inject 'sudo' into the compile command. the file /home/rob/src/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc EXISTS, contrary to what the compiler check in config.log says and this gcc compiler has permissions 775. So, im not able to understand why compile check in configure is failing??

Answer (score 0):

changed 2 items in the standard 'build_android.sh' to get at least output in the target directories as per $PREFIX...

abbreviated list of changes

```
NDK=/home/rob/src/android-ndk-r8
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86
export PATH=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:$PATH
```

...

```
mkdir -p $PREFIX
..
make clean
```

1. export 2. create target dir

The compiler check that i complained about in the original faq is still there...

> /home/rob/src/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
>   is unable to create an executable file. C compiler test failed.

But i got output binaries in the correct folder so, i'll move them to the phone and test from the CLI in a shell to see whether i can create WEBM files that will play on the phone.